# .Net Core 2.2 File.ReadAllBytes(fileName) throws System.UnauthorizedAccessException for UNC path

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, iis-8, asp.net-core-2.2, unc

I would like get a certain file as byte array in my .net core 2.2 application. The app uses iis and is started like this:

```
new WebHostBuilder()
                .UseKestrel(opt => opt.AddServerHeader = false)
                .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                .UseIISIntegration()
                .UseStartup<Startup>();
```

The application pool for the site uses a dedicated service user. This user has access rights to the share and is in the security list for the UNC-Path-Folder and also for the file directly.

However when I try to read the file like this:

```
_fileContent = File.ReadAllBytes("\\working\UNC\Path\File.pdf");
```

I get the following exception:

```
System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path '\\working\UNC\Path\File.pdf' is denied.
   at System.IO.FileStream.ValidateFileHandle(SafeFileHandle fileHandle)
   at System.IO.FileStream.CreateFileOpenHandle(FileMode mode, FileShare share, FileOptions options)
   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options)
   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize)
   at System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(String path)
```

The UNC path is currently actually a directory on the local machine. Therefore I have tried to load the file by using a **windows path** like: "c:\Path\File.pdf". And this **is working just fine**! Therefore I conclude that the problem has actually nothing to do with security permissions.

Can someone pls give some light into this issue?

Comment: The exception says "System.UnauthorizedAccessException", therefore it is security related. You should give the ApplicationPool's identity read permission on the UNC share.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the comment of UNOPARATOR I found the problem. As accessing the file directly with the windows path was working it couldn't be a problem with the security itself but as accessing over the unc path gave the exception it is actually obvious that there is a problem with the security settings of the network share. And indeed after analyzing again the share I noticed that I have checked the share settings not on the root folder of the share - but on a child folder inside the share. As soon I gave read permission on the root share everything was working fine!